# Count frequencies in a range

Tags: r, count, range

Assuming that I have a following data.frame:

```
var=c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","B","C")
time_sec=c(11.2,7.38,148.05,141.77,44.44,293.23,111.08,35.22,59.01)
dur_sec=c(7,3,2,1,5,2,4,6,2)
headers=c("var","time_sec","dur_sec")

g=data.frame(var, time_sec,dur_sec)
g
```

This is my output:

```
var time_sec    duration_sec
A   11.2         7
B   7.38         3
C   148.05       2
A   141.77       1
B   44.44        5
C   293.23       2
A   111.08       4
B   35.22        6
C   59.01        2
```

What is the fastest way to get a table containing the number of frequencies per variable in the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th minute? Also, I would like to have in the output a column containing the sum of the counts.

This is what I imagine to have:

```
range (min) var  Freq  Sum (sec)
0-1         A    1     157.25
            B    3
            C    1
1-2         A    1     111.08
            B    0
            C    0
2-3         A    1     141.77
            B    0
            C    1
3-4         A    0     293.13
            B    0
            C    1
```

Comment: You can create the `range` using `cut` i.e. `library(data.table); setDT(g)[, range := cut(time_sec/60, breaks = 0:5)];
 g[, .(Freq=.N, Sum = sum(time_sec)), .(range, var)]`

Comment: @acrun: I applied your code to my original data and have some questions. The output in my data showed under `NA` under `range`, however, `Freq` and `Sum` are filled. Does it have something to do with the `breaks`? Can you explain to me why you chose `breaks=0:5` and what does it stand for. Thank you

Comment: @acrun: I think, I realized why there is `NA` in the column `range`. Some of my variables start at 0.00. Probably, your code does not include it in the `(0,1] range`.

Comment: I don't think Akrun will hear you if you mention him by using @acrun

Comment: I used @acrun because this is what is suggested in the mini-Markdown formatting suggestions below the edited window. Don't understand your comment. Can you help me out with what you are referring to? What should I do instead. Thanks

Comment: He is called @akrun ?

Comment: It could be related to the breaks.  Suppose, if you have values that are outside the range, it will be NAs.  I choose 0:5 based on your example as it were within 5 minutes.  Also, based on the expected, I think you also need to expand the dataset to account for the 0 values

Comment: @lukeA: Oj oj oj...you are totally RIGHT o_O. I am blind. Sorry. Thanks for the tip

Comment: @akrun: I tried to substitute your `breaks= 0:5` with `breaks = seq(0,5)+0` in order to include variables which start at 0 sec. These are marked as `NA`. It didn't work, though.